# Как вывести объекты яндекс карты в листинге за картой?

Tags: wordpress, yandex-maps-api

Есть карта,к примеру,дом клика:
https://domclick.ru/search/on-map?deal_type=sale&category=living&offer_type=house&sw=55.90226%2C36.914587&ne=55.911022%2C36.955786&from=topline2020&utm_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fvk.com%2F

Вопрос в следующем: как реализовать вывод одиночных объектов и кластера при клике на точку на карте слева,листингом?Похожий функционал реализован на циане.Куда копать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выбор методов оформления и реализации полей и списков целиком и полностью зависит от вашего ТЗ и технических возможностей. Что-то посоветовать тут сложно.

Получить же список объектов выбранного кластера можно через [getGeoObjects()](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/ClusterPlacemark.html), а данные отдельных меток доступны сразу на объекте, прослушивание клика на котором сработало:

```
clusterer.events.add(['click'], function (e) {
    var target = e.get('target'),
    type = e.get('type');
    // Событие произошло на кластере.
    if (typeof target.getGeoObjects != 'undefined') {
        console.log(target.getGeoObjects())
    // Событие произошло на геообъекте.
    } else {
        console.log(target)
    }
});
```

Проверить работу кода можете на любом [примере с кластерами](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/clusterer_icon_hover) из песочницы Яндекса, добавив в них этот код.

Comment: Забавно,я сам пришёл к этому же решению до того как увидел этот ответ.Спасибо!